# The other days v.s. the other day

Tags: word-usage

As far as I'm concerned,the other day can mean a specific day in recent days.
However,if something happens not just one day in recent days,can I use "the other days"?
For example

> It was raining the other days.
>   →means it was raining day for not just one day recently.

Or,under this condition,do we also just use "the other day"?

Comment: You're trying to single-handedly extend an idiom beyond its scope. Sometimes that works, sometimes it doesn't. This time it doesn't, and trying to do it anyway is likely to get you blank looks as the native speakers present assume you simply screwed up the base idiom.

Comment: @Robusto I'll bear it in my mind. Anyway,thanks for reminding me about this nightmare scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of a *standalone* sentence, the singular makes sense:

> ✔ The other day, I met a clown on the street.

But as a *standalone* sentence, the plural is unidiomatic:

> ✘ The other days, I met a clown on the street.

---

However, in the right context, *the other days* is perfectly acceptable:

> ✔ ***On Monday last week, my walk to work was uneventful.*** The *other days*, I met a clown on the street.

There is nothing unusual about that. It's a perfectly normal application of words, with a perfectly understandable plural usage. (And it's understood that *the other days* means *the other days of the week*.)

---

In the acceptable version, *the other days* is used in contrast to the one day (or it could be in contrast to multiple stated days) when something different happened.

Further, it's actually the use of *other* that requires some kind of contrasting statement, not *days* itself:

> ✘ The *other* pieces of fruit were fresh.
>   ✔ ***One piece of fruit was rotten.*** The *other* pieces of fruit were fresh.

So, your sentence is perfectly fine—as long as it's preceded by something else that indicates one or more days when it was *not* raining:

> ✔ ***That week, it was a nice day on Monday.*** Unfortunately, it rained *the other days*.

If the first sentence is left out, the second sentence is still *grammatical*, but it becomes confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your rather comprehensive and useful answer to deal with my question completely. It's really nic of you to do so.：)

Answer (score 0):

`The other day` means recently. So, it's not necessarily about one day (for "recently" means "at a time that was not long ago"). Use `the other day`, not `the other days`, to mean it. It's a phrase to remember and use as it is.

If you want to emphasize the fact that it was raining not just for one day, you may want to use `for a few days` or `for several days`:

> It was raining for a few days.
>
> For several days it was raining so heavily!